# Action Class in Struts 1.x and Struts 2.x

Tags: java, class, frameworks, struts

I have a query that in Struts 1.x , in Action class we have Action,Dispatch Action,Lookup Dispatch Action. In the same way in struts 2.x what all action's we have?

Comment: Why not just look at the API docs?

Answer (score 0):

In Struts 1 DispatchAction helps us in grouping a set of related functions into a single action. In Struts 2 all the Actions by default provide this functionality. To use this functionality we need to create different methods with the similar signature of the execute() method, only the name of the method changes. It’s a useful mechanism to avoid create separate action classe for each function.

for more info you can visit the following url: [url1](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/dispatchaction-in-struts-2-example-1.html) and [url2](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-dispatchaction-example/) . Hope that helps